# Make same ajax call multiple times with different parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two loops. The first one saves multiple urls into the array "tempUrls". In the second one I want to send every url in the "tempUrls"-Array to a function called "ajaxCall". But for some reason I only get the last added url into the ajax-call. Everything else just goes missing and I don't know why.

If you need any further elaboration, feel free to ask!

Thank you very much

EDIT: This is all the relevant code of my program. What I am doing is I get the list of urls from the first pages. Then I call the urls I found and get the meta-robot information out if them.

```
 function startChecker() {
    for (var n = gNumOfSites; n > 0; n--) {
        console.log('in');
        var nextUrl = gUrlSnippet + n;

        ajaxCall(nextUrl, extractData);
    }
}

function ajaxCall(url, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: callback
    });
}

function extractData(res) {
    var tempUrls = [];
    var html = res.responseText;
    var linkUrl;

    var links = $(html).find('.tags li');

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = $(links[i]).find('a');

        linkUrl = $(link).attr("href");
        gUrls.push(linkUrl);
        tempUrls.push(linkUrl);

        var anchor = $(link).text();
        gAnchors.push(anchor);
        console.log('anchor');
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < tempUrls.length; j++) {
        var urlExtract = gUrlSnippet.split('/');
        var nextUrl = 'http://' + urlExtract[2] + tempUrls[j];
        console.log(nextUrl);

        ajaxCall(nextUrl, function(res) {
            getRobots(res, nextUrl);
        });
    }
    tempUrls = [];
}

function getRobots(res, nextUrl) {
    var str = '';
    var html = res.responseText;
    var robots = $(html).filter('meta[name=robots]');
    if (robots.length === 0) {
        str = "not found";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < robots.length; i++) {
            str = str + $(robots[i]).attr("content");
        }
    }
    gRobots.push(nextUrl + str);

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        setText();
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ajax calls are asynchronous, you are overwriting the previous call data each time you make the next call. You may want to look into returning the values from each call to a separate location, say a different index in an array.

Provide a Plunker with more code and I can help you out a little better. Can't quite get a grasp of where your data is stored from the AJAX call.

Comment: I pasted the relevant parts of the code for you in the original question :)

Comment: I'm looking for where your data is being saved.

Comment: It is saved in 3 global variables: gUrls, gAnchors and gRobots.

Comment: @BrianGerhards "because ajax calls are asynchronous" how you can overwrite previous call data? You can overwrite only response. Data already sent.  I can give you example then you call `$.ajax` within `.forEach` and you gonna have multiple responses.

Comment: This is where I am stuck to. Because I am definitely sending multiple ajax calls out.

Comment: @Algram If you want to wait until you get information you can try: `async: false,` after `type: 'GET',` in your function.

Comment: async: false you mean? That is bad design and can always be avoided.

I added a Plunker which should explain what the code does: http://plnkr.co/edit/FO3fsBe3Ow3NMGEBtK3u?p=preview

Comment: @Algram I'm not telling you it's good design, but if you use ajax in the loop you will have to be ready to have multiple response.

Comment: @SouXin Yeah but there has to be a better option and I want to find it :)

Comment: You are calling the AJAX call from StartChecker. This does not include the HTTP://. You need to add the HTTP:// somehow, maybe like 'ajaxCall("http://" + nextUrl, extractData);'. Looking into the other issue now